# Create spacing in data list

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

How do I space out the output, i considered using the each() method but I couldn't figure out how to use it. I can do this with Django for loop without ajax, but with ajax it seems the for loop tag doesn't work here's the code.

```
current output = 1.0768411833.01.28164125.6340.91000

expected output = 1.07684 11833.0 1.28164 125.634 0.91000

<h2 id="prices"></h2>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const doAjaxWithDelay = (delay) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            var data = $(this).data()
            $.ajax({
                url: "/price",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = data;
                    console.log(data)
                }
            }).done(() => {

                doAjaxWithDelay(5000)

            })
        }, delay)
    }

    doAjaxWithDelay(0)
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value being returned in `data` in the success function?

Comment: in my function based views, data=[] and is being populated by values selenium scrapes. i am also returning Httpresponse(data). also, print(data) gives ['1.07637', '11844.4', '1.27933', '125.736', '0.90883'] as output in my terminal.

Comment: so its returning you array ?

Comment: @Swati yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the the value of `data` in the success function is an array of numbers, just do:

```
success: function(data) {
  document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = data.join(' ');
}
```